# Multiple UITextField in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uialertview

I use an UIAlertView for display a registration form with username, email and password. But I have a little problem with UITextField:

**Error:**
**NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'textFieldIndex (2) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields**

My code

```
// iOS7
        UIAlertView *registerAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Register"
                                       message:@"Enter your username, email & password."
                                       delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Register", nil];
        [registerAlertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

        UITextField *username = [registerAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        UITextField *email = [registerAlertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
        UITextField *password = [registerAlertView textFieldAtIndex:2];
        password.secureTextEntry = YES;

        [registerAlertView show];
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Although rmaddy is right, It might be good to point out UIAlertController does support multi input fields where the UIAlertView doesn't.  ;)

Comment: Disregard. I see your code is for ios7. UIAlertView has been deprecated for UIAlertController in iOS8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alert style `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` only provides one text field. At most you can get two text fields with the `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput` style.

Your code attempts to use 3 text fields. That isn't supported.

You need to create or find a custom alert view-like control if you want to have three text fields.